# Blank page with no errors when using ng-route

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie to Angular, I've started working with v- 1.6 and the Ng-route doesn't seems to work...once i've set the routes in the app.config - i get blank page with no errors....

Here is the app.config.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('try', ['ngRoute']);
    myApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function(e, r) {

        e.when('/home', {
            template: "<h1>Home</h1>"
        }).when('/about', {
            template: "<h1>about</h1>"
        }).when('/', {
            template: "<blog-list></blog-list>"
        });
    }]);
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7HljXqyd4GSjQC2Yc3ht?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the application, `you should call any route`, as you are not doing that none of your routes are calling.

See, I had added an otherwise route. I updated the code from your plunker.

**Otherwise method, which is the default route when none of the others get a match.**

```
var myApp = angular.module('try', ['ngRoute','blogList']);
myApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function(e, r) {
    r.hashPrefix('');
    r.html5Mode(true);
    e.
    when('/home', {
        template: "<h1>Home</h1>"
    }).when('/about', {
        template: "<h1>about</h1>"
    }).when('/', {
        template: "<blog-list></blog-list>"
    }).otherwise(
        { redirectTo: 'home' }
    );
}]);
```

[**Updated plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/5MBxU6pD6QkW48ZoclGC?p=preview)

Comment: thanks - but the links dosen't works...when i manually go to localhost/about i get nothing - also when i go to / - i should get the 'blog-list' component ...

Comment: add,`<base href="/" />` in your `index.html`

Comment: thanks - now the links works - but the  the 'blog-list' component still doesn't...wonder why...

Comment: add your directive to module and check

Comment: `angular.module('try', ['ngRoute','blogList']);` add this